# flutter singlechildscrol view how to controll the scroll property of parent

Tags: flutter, listview, singlechildscrollview

i want that if the list of black containers are at the top most position or at the bottom most part then it should scroll up along with the red container

how to achieve it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9grO.png)

help me in this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKwVv.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.